# How to read data in background in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an app in React Native, that uses the bluetooth connection to read data from external devices.

I need a way to continue to read this data in background when, for example, the user starts a reading session and put the app in background.

What should I use to do this?

My code is divided in two parts:

- Scan and Connect
- Reading Data from external devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a background service for this. The following link for Android will help you. 
github => [react-native-foreground-service](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-foreground-service)

If you want, you can do it yourself as described on the RN official site. But you'll have to write Java code for it.
React Native => [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)